# Fix Axios Error ECONNREFUSED on local domain with no proxy

Tags: node.js, axios, nightmare

I'm bumping into this stupid issue with Axios.

I'm trying to send a local POST request to my basic local Symfony app with the following piece of code that is a nightmare JS crawler:
Yuzu.fun is my local dev domain with an entry in /etc/hosts to resolve it, the app is running on port 80.

```
await axios.request({
  url: 'http://yuzu.fun/app_dev.php/api/path/to/endpoint',
  headers: {
    'key': 'xxxxxx'
  },
  method: 'post',
  proxy: false,
  data: {
    image_data: data
  }
})
.then(function (response) {
  map_hash = response.message;
  console.log('buildMap', map_hash);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.error('upload failed:', error);
});
```

When i run my script, here is the error i get:

```
upload failed: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
syscall: 'connect',
address: '127.0.0.1',
port: 80,
config: 
 { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
 transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
 transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
 timeout: 0,
 xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
 xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
 maxContentLength: -1,
 validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
 headers: 
  { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
    key: 'xxxxx',
    'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0',
    'Content-Length': 4173 },
 method: 'post',
 url: 'http://yuzu.fun/app_dev.php/api/path/to/endpoint',
 proxy: false,
 data: '{"image_data":"imagedatainbase64"}' },
request: 
 Writable {
 _writableState: 
  WritableState {
    objectMode: false,
    highWaterMark: 16384,
    finalCalled: false,
    needDrain: false,
    ending: false,
    ended: false,
    finished: false,
    destroyed: false,
    decodeStrings: true,
    defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
    length: 0,
    writing: false,
    corked: 0,
    sync: true,
    bufferProcessing: false,
    onwrite: [Function: bound onwrite],
    writecb: null,
    writelen: 0,
    bufferedRequest: null,
    lastBufferedRequest: null,
    pendingcb: 0,
    prefinished: false,
    errorEmitted: false,
    bufferedRequestCount: 0,
    corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
 writable: true,
 domain: null,
 _events: 
  { response: [Function: handleResponse],
    error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
 _eventsCount: 2,
 _maxListeners: undefined,
 _options: 
  { maxRedirects: 21,
    maxBodyLength: 10485760,
    protocol: 'http:',
    path: '/app_dev.php/api/path/to/endpoint',
    method: 'post',
    headers: [Object],
    agent: undefined,
    auth: undefined,
    hostname: 'yuzu.fun',
    port: null,
    nativeProtocols: [Object],
    pathname: '/app_dev.php/api/path/to/endpoint' },
 _ended: false,
 _ending: true,
 _redirectCount: 0,
 _redirects: [],
 _requestBodyLength: 4173,
 _requestBodyBuffers: [ [Object] ],
 _onNativeResponse: [Function],
 _currentRequest: 
  ClientRequest {
    domain: null,
    _events: [Object],
    _eventsCount: 6,
    _maxListeners: undefined,
    output: [],
    outputEncodings: [],
    outputCallbacks: [],
    outputSize: 0,
    writable: true,
    _last: true,
    upgrading: false,
    chunkedEncoding: false,
    shouldKeepAlive: false,
    useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
    sendDate: false,
    _removedConnection: false,
    _removedContLen: false,
    _removedTE: false,
    _contentLength: null,
    _hasBody: true,
    _trailer: '',
    finished: false,
    _headerSent: true,
    socket: [Object],
    connection: [Object],
    _header: 'POST /app_dev.php/api/path/to/endpoint HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8\r\nkey: xxxxx\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nContent-Length: 4173\r\nHost: yuzu.fun\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
    _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
    agent: [Object],
    socketPath: undefined,
    timeout: undefined,
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/app_dev.php/api/path/to/endpoint',
    _ended: false,
    res: null,
    aborted: undefined,
    timeoutCb: null,
    upgradeOrConnect: false,
    parser: null,
    maxHeadersCount: null,
    _redirectable: [Circular],
    [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
 _currentUrl: 'http://yuzu.fun//app_dev.php/api/path/to/endpoint' },
response: undefined }
```

I tried to post to a random endpoint to check if the connection was working when reaching a live domain and it's OK but it doesn't work locally. 
When i check stackoverflow or forums i see people mentioning proxies issues so i forced it to false but i don't think that something i'm concerned with.

This code was first written with `request.post()` but i need to have Axios Promises benefits. When the code was written with request, the local domain was reachable correctly. So i exclude the fact that nightmare could interfere with the domain resolution.

Does anyone have any idea of was could go wrong here?

Thanks in advance!